# How to solve static files of other app can't load to my app in Django?

Tags: django, django-templates

I use `https://github.com/adamcharnock/django-adminlte2` as my template base. However, when debug false, static file use in that template can't not load. I tried to use `python manage.py collectstatic` but it doesn't fixed. How to make to load that template static files? May I need to copy all adminlte2 static file to project static folder?
I use default wsgi server and there is no apache, nginx. 
I am totally new to django and python.

Comment: Please checkout the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/deployment/

Comment: I already read and run collectstatic  but static file use in django-adminlte2 doesn't copy to static folder.  Yes, I don't have severer because it is in development state. Moreover, I read a lot both documentation and other online explanation but they are mention about how to apply static file which write by myself or use by myself. I want to know is how to make the application automatically know the django-adminlte2 static file when debug is false.